# How to call security function for only the last candle in pinescript which is fetching a tuple

Tags: security, tuples, pine-script

I am trying to call security function whose expression is a function call as shown:
e.g.

```
 [o, h] = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", f())
```

I want this to happen only for the present last candle so I am using

```
if barstate.islast
    [o, h] = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", f())
```

I have defined the function f() outside the if block e.g.

```
f() => [open, high]
if barstate.islast
    [o, h] = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", f())
```

Now the problem is the error,
line 109: Cannot call 'security' or 'financial' inside 'if' or 'for'

Is there a way to do this? i.e. security call for only last candle for the requirement?

Why? Because multiple security calls are slowing down the script. They are working fine, but it is taking lot of time to load if you change script or timeframe.

Comment: `security()` must always be called in the main code block, because the entire series is loaded on the first bar, irrespective of the number of times you use it in your script. Please edit your question and post your entire script. There's probably something the community can advise to improve the performance.